# Anyway to find out when Facebook comments are done loading on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm using jQuery to equalize some of the column heights on a page. The problem is, I have Facebook comments loading on a page, and they load by the time my code to equalize column heights is done. So I'm wondering if there is anyway to pass a callback to the Facebook comments (or if there is a more elegant way of doing this, I'm all ears).

Comment: How is the Facebook comments box implemented? Is it an IFRAME element? In that case, you want to bind the `load` event of the IFRAME...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've run into this problem on my own as well. Here is how I've managed to handle the problem. Keep in mind `equalizeColumns` is my custom function, yours may be named something else.

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
  FB.Event.subscribe("xfbml.render", function(response){equalizeColumns()});
  FB.Event.subscribe("comment.create", function(response){equalizeColumns()});
  FB.Event.subscribe("comment.remove", function(response){equalizeColumns()});
  FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function(response){equalizeColumns()});
  FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove", function(response){equalizeColumns()});
});</script>
```

As you can see in the example above, binding to the [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) should give you what you need. In particular, the `xfbml.render` hook is essentially the `onload` event. Unfortunately, I've only had minor success with the other hooks (which you will need if someone posts a comment, removes a comment, "Likes" a post, or "Unlikes" a post - respectively).

If you add a `setTimeout` call to the equalizeColumns call, you may have more success.